# Local signup strategy not working - redirecting to failure route but cannot work out what the issue is

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to set up authentication using passport and am starting with my local strategy. However, for some reason signup is failing and I cannot work out what the issue is with my code. Here's my server file:

```
var express             =       require('express'),
app                     =       express(),
bodyParser              =       require('body-parser'),
mongoose                =       require('mongoose'),
expressSanitizer        =       require('express-sanitizer'),
methodOverride          =       require('method-override'),
passport                =       require('passport'),
flash                   =       require('connect-flash'),
Blog                    =       require('./models/blog'),
Comment                 =       require('./models/comment'),
moment                  =       require('moment'),
session                 =       require('express-session'),
cookieParser            =       require('cookie-parser'),
port                    =       process.env.PORT || 8080;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/NUFC_blog2');

require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for  configuration

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// passport config
app.use(session({ secret: 'toonaresocool'})); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // messages

// routes
require('./routes.js')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport

// Listening route
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
```

And here's my signup route:

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {

// route for home page
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('landing.ejs');
});

// show signup form

app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
res.render('register.ejs', { message: req.flash('signupMessage') });
});

// process user signup

app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
successRedirect     :   '/blogs',
failureRedirect     :   '/signup',
failureFlash        :   true
}));
};
```

Local strategy:

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = function(passport) {

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
});
});

// LOCAL SIGNUP STRATEGY

passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
usernameField   :'username', 
passwordField   : 'password',
passReqToCallback: true 
},
function(req, username, password, done) {
// asynchronous
// user.findOne won't work unless data is sent back
process.nextTick(function() {
    // find user whose username is same as on form
    // check to see if the user trying to log in already exists
User.findOne({ 'local.username' : username }, function(err, user){
    // if errors return the error
if(err)
    return done(err);
// check to see if there's a user with that username already
if (user) {
    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That username is already in use'))
} else {
    // if there is no user with the email
    // create new user
    var newUser     = User();
    newUser.local.username = username;
    newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);

    // save user
    newUser.save(function(err) {
        if(err)
            throw err;
        return done(null, newUser);
    });
}
});     
});
}));
};
```

Here's my user model:

```
var mongoose        =           require('mongoose'),
bcrypt                  =           require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

local           : {
    username    : String, 
    password    : String,
    image       : String,
    email       : String
},
});

userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

And finally my signup form! :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Node Authentication</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">    <!-- load bootstrap css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!-- load fontawesome -->
<style>
    body        { padding-top:80px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

<h1><span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span> Signup</h1>
<!-- show any messages that come back with authentication -->
<% if (message.length > 0) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
<% } %>

<!-- LOGIN FORM -->
<form action="/signup" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Signup</button>
</form>

<hr>

<p>Already have an account? <a href="/login">Login</a></p>
<p>Or go <a href="/">home</a>.</p>

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to signup nothing is being added to the db and I just get redirected back to signup, which is my redirect for failure. Any ideas??

Comment: Use debugger, and explore errors. I think there might be mistakes in configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem which I see it that in **signup.ejs** you are naming *email*

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
```

But in **passport.js** it is *username*

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField   :'username', 
  passwordField   : 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true 
},
```

change **passport.js** to

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField   :'email', 
  passwordField   : 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true 
},
```